# Does a woman need to appoint a shomer when eating a meal or working before mincha?

Tags: tefilla, women

Halacha says that once the time for Mincha arrives, unless one appoints a Shomer, one may not sit down to eat a meal or get initially involved in certain forms of work lest he forget to Daven. Would this apply to a woman who always davens Mincha

Comment: Why would you think there's a difference? Edit that info into your question to make it clearer what you're assuming and what you're looking for in an answer.

Comment: The shulchan aruch does not distinguish between genders for this (nor does anyone prior to him) so seemingly they all held the rules ought be the same.

Comment: Probably depends on whether women are obligated to daven mincha.